How to deal with mongo db many to many relationship
What is best practice for handle many to many relationship in mongo db.
Example I have team, user 1 team can have many user, and 1 user can have many team.
So what solution is the best:
-Solution 1 : store in both user and team, and when update or create do it on both.
-Solution 2: make relation table like a traditional way in relational database like (mysql)
What is the best solution to use, or anyone can suggest other solution.
PS: If you have any solution in laravel is will be excellent

Does this post help: Designing Many-to-Many relationships in MongoDB (instead of relational tables)

Thank you I think this post is actually helping me, but it still have some confuse to me. If I want query in a both way team with user inside and user with team inside. So I must store data into both right.

I think store data in one document, and use lookup when query from another document
